# Why can't I inject controller in integration test?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have my integration test where I inject dummyService and dummyController. When I test them for notNull I have dummyService injected, but dummyController is not. Why is it so? Both are spring managed beans, so it seems like bots should be injected into integration test, isnt' it?

```
class DummyTests{
    DummyService dummyService;
    DummyController dummyController;
    @Test
    void testDummyController() {
        assertNotNull( dummyService );
        assertNotNull( dummyController ); // FAILS ON THIS LINE
    }
}
```

Comment: A thing to watch for is where you put your integration tests, the need to be in a path that tells the framework it needs a "complete" setup. If I remember it correctly: test/integration.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples how to do integration testing and testing controllers: [Grails Doc](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#9.2%20Integration%20Testing).

There you have to create controllers via their constructor. 
So `DummyController dummyController = new DummyController()` should do the job.